# Spring framework bind form array property

Tags: spring, webforms, bind

```
// my form
public class myForm {
private double[] myField;

public double[] getMyField(){
    return myField;
}

public void setMyField(double[] myField){
    this.myField = myField;
}
}

// my jsp
...
...
<c:set var="i" value="0"/>
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="data">
<form:input path="myField[${$i}]"/>
<c:set var="i">${i + 1}</c:set>
</c:forEach>
...
...
```

After spring render jsp generate this code ;

```
<input type="text" value="0.0" name="myField0" id="myField0"/>
<input type="text" value="0.0" name="myField1" id="myField1"/>
<input type="text" value="0.0" name="myField2" id="myField2"/>
...
...
```

Spring cant bind my form on controller , because form names not valid (myField0, myField1..) . If i change names with firebug (as myField[0], myField[1] etc.) initBinder works and i catch my form data on controller. How can i solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Collection in your form instead of an array :

```
public class myForm {
    private Collection<Double> myField;

    public Collection<Double> getMyField(){
        return myField;
    }

    public void setMyField(Collection<Double> myField){
        this.myField = myField;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use a Collection? Why can't he use an array?. Also, any collection is allowed?